# Is there a way to install .update packages automatically?

Tags: update-packages

Is there a way to install the .update package automatically via command line / powershell?

The way that I know is to install it via `/sitecore/admin/UpdateInstallationWizard.aspx`.
I'm looking for a way so that no manual interaction is necessary in order to update our servers since we have quite a few of them.

Note: Due to security concerns we are not allowed to use SPE.

Comment: You can use C# code as well, the code can be gleaned from Sitecore.Update.dll and also updateinstallationwizard.aspx. For command line I believe there was a option available with Sitecore Courier

Answer (score 1):

Using the below PowerShell command you can install update packages, Sitecore packages, courier package:

Install-UpdatePackage [-Path]  [[-RollbackPackagePath] ] -UpgradeAction <Preview | Upgrade> -InstallMode <Install | Update>

Reference: https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/appendix/packaging/install-updatepackage

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately we are not allowed to use the SPE due to security concerns of the customer. Is there a way without SPE?

Comment: C# .exe with code taken from Sitecore Courier(Install Update packages)

Answer (score 1):

TDS Package deployer auto deploys update packages.

https://github.com/HedgehogDevelopment/SitecorePackageDeployer/releases

https://www.teamdevelopmentforsitecore.com/Blog/sitecore-package-deployer

Comment: Not supported for Sitecore 10.